# Getting the text of the last directory of a given string with the delimiters of /

Tags: c++, string, parsing, url, stl

Given a URL (which is a string) such as this:

www.testsite.com/pictures/banners/whatever/

I want to be able to get the characters of the last directory in the URL (in this case it's "whatever", I want to also remove the forward slashes). What would be the most efficient way to do this?

Thanks for any help

Comment: You could always start with [`std::string::rfind()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rfind).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

std::string getlastcomponent(std::string s) {
  if (s.size() > 0 && s[s.size()-1] == '/')
    s.resize(s.size() - 1);
  size_t i = s.find_last_of('/');
  return (i != s.npos) ? s.substr(i+1) : s;
}

int main() {
  std::string s1 = "www.testsite.com/pictures/banners/whatever/";
  std::string s2 = "www.testsite.com/pictures/banners/whatever";
  std::string s3 = "whatever/";
  std::string s4 = "whatever";
  std::cout << getlastcomponent(s1) << '\n';
  std::cout << getlastcomponent(s2) << '\n';
  std::cout << getlastcomponent(s3) << '\n';
  std::cout << getlastcomponent(s4) << '\n';
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Get the length and push every letter from last ( at example pseudo code:

```
x = string.length()
while(X != 0)
{
CharVector.push(string.at(x)); 
x--;
if(string.at(x) == "\") break;
}
```

then you got revetahw instead of whatever.
Then just swap it with this fucntion:

```
string ReverseString( const string& word )
{
    std::string l_bla;
    bla.reserve(word.size());
    for ( string::size_type x = word.length ( ); x > 0; x-- )
    {

        l_bla += word.at ( x -1 );

    }
    return l_bla;
}
```

so you got whatever

Comment: This is a pretty inefficient and convoluted solution. Just `rfind` the backslash and `substr()` to a new string.